# curl / wget failed Connecton time out error

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to update my Web Host Manager and other applications on my instance and now I am getting errors when using "CURL" or "WGET".

```
> Executing /usr/local/directadmin/plugins/custombuild/admin/build
> imagemagickDownloading ImageMagick-7.0.8-46.tar.gz...
> --2019-10-13 16:39:46-- http://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/imagick/ImageMagick-7.0.8-46.tar.gz
> Resolving files.directadmin.com (files.directadmin.com)...
> 69.162.69.58, 104.128.54.74, 185.42.221.168 Connecting to files.directadmin.com (files.directadmin.com)|69.162.69.58|:80...
> failed: Connection timed out. Connecting to files.directadmin.com
> (files.directadmin.com)|104.128.54.74|:80... failed: Connection timed
> out. Connecting to files.directadmin.com
> (files.directadmin.com)|185.42.221.168|:80... failed: Connection timed
> out. Retrying.
```

I have already check to make sure none of the IPs and domains are blocked by the GCS firewall and the instances software firewalls but none of the attempt to connnect to external hosts via CLI are working. I am not able to complete any updates to the host outside of GCS network. Downloading and uploading to the instance via FTP or SFTP is much too slow.

It is not the scripts nor PHP because no connections to remote hosts are being accepted.

Comment: Looks like a connectivity issue. As a first step, could you check if an External IP is mapped to the instance and try the command `traceroute files.directadmin.com` ?

Comment: @mebius99 I am not sure what I am looking for because I setup this instance a few years ago and had no issue.  None of the setting changed that I know of and I did not getting any notice of changes by Google.  It seems that I never installed traceroute and yum cannot install it cause I am not able to connect to sites from the host to the internet.

Comment: @ HipHopServers, what about External IP, is it bound to the instance? Next, you should check the "VM instance details => Network interface details => Routes". There should be "Default route to the Internet" with Destination = 0.0.0.0/0. Also, please look at the "Egress analysis".

Comment: @mebius99 you can see a screen shoot of my network settings at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/c0zVhh7Uf_I/vah6uM28DgAJ as I thought the same thing but I did not show were the egress is being blocked.